# Servicios sql deshabilitados

Tags: windows, sql-server-2017

tengo un problema que anteriormente deshabilite todos los servicios de sql server, ahora no se como habilitarlos o que esten activos o algo parecido, porque no me salen el la lista de servicios del administrador de tareas, estoy en windows 10, ya intente con desintalar he instalar sql server mananger studio, intente haciendo una limpieza al equipo pero nada, alguna sugerencia por favor gracias.

de los servicios que no me funcionan es el sql server configuration mananger, porque por ahi consegui en internet que puedo activarlos pero ya no se que mas realizar

Answer (score 2):

**OPCION 1) Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
Si lo tienes instalado, basta con registrar el servidor y desde ahí tienes acceso a para INICIAR, PAUSAR y PARAR los servicios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**OPCION 2) Desde el Administrador ¡de Servicios.**
Pulsa <kbd>TECLA WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> y escrive "Servicios" o "Services"
Desde ahí busca el servicio y tienes las opciones para INICIAR, PAUSAR y PARAR.
Si no te aparece es que no está instalado correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**OPCION 3) Desde la línea de Comandos.**
Pulsa <kbd>TECLA WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> y escrive `"cmd"` y pulsa click derecho para seleccionar "Ejecutar como Administrador"
Escribe para pararlo:

```
net stop "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)"
```

Donde la parte que hay entre comillas es el nombre que aparece en la pantalla anterior de "Servicios"

Para arrancarlo:

```
net start "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)"
```